# Select dates missing data in a range

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgres table `test_table` that looks like this:

```
     date    | test_hour
------------+-----------
 2000-01-01 |         1
 2000-01-01 |         2
 2000-01-01 |         3
 2000-01-02 |         1
 2000-01-02 |         2
 2000-01-02 |         3
 2000-01-02 |         4
 2000-01-03 |         1
 2000-01-03 |         2
```

I need to select all the `date`s which don't have `test_hour` = 1, 2, and 3, so it should return

```
     date    
------------
 2000-01-03
```

Here is what I have tried:

`SELECT date FROM test_table WHERE test_hour NOT IN (SELECT generate_series(1,3));`

But that only returns dates that have extra hours beyond 1, 2, 3

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation and conditional `HAVING` clauses, like so:

```
SELECT mydate
FROM mytable
GROUP BY mydate
HAVING 
    MAX(CASE WHEN test_hour = 1 THEN 1 END) != 1
    OR MAX(CASE WHEN test_hour = 2 THEN 1 END) != 1
    OR MAX(CASE WHEN test_hour = 3 THEN 1 END) != 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility would be to join it against the series (or another subquery containing the hours) and do a [distinct] count on the hours aggregatet per date:

```
select date from tst
inner join (select generate_series(1,3) "hour") hours on hours.hour = tst.hour
group by tst.date
having count(distinct tst.hour) < 3;
```

or

```
select date from tst
where hour in (select generate_series(1,3))
group by date
having count(distinct tst.hour) < 3;
```

[You don't need the distinct if date/hour combinations in Your table are unique]

Answer (score 0):

A solution using [set difference](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-union.html), giving you exactly the rows that are missing:

```
(SELECT DISTINCT
  date, all_hour
  FROM test_table
  CROSS JOIN generate_series(1,3) all_hour)
EXCEPT
(TABLE test_table)
```

And a solution using an [array aggregate](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) and the [array contains operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html):

```
SELECT date
FROM test_table
GROUP BY date
HAVING NOT array_agg(test_hour) @> ARRAY(SELECT generate_series(1,3))
```

([online demos](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=3fa31b49fdb9d836a98dfcd153355e73))